# What is the correct way to allow a user to delete their account with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user accounts. What is the correct way to let users delete their accounts?

My devise setup already has an overridden registrations controller

> devise_for :users, :path_names =>
>   {:sign_up => "register"}, :controllers
>   => {:registrations => 'registrations'}

This is how I've tried to setup the account removal process:

registrations_controller.rb

```
def delete_account
    #remove data associated with account, then the user object itself
end
```

routes.rb

```
  map.delete_account 'delete_account', :controller => 'registrations', :action => 'delete_account'
```

and try to link to it

```
<%= button_to 'temo', delete_account_path %>
```

I get this error when I click the link

```
Unknown action
AbstractController::ActionNotFound
```

Why isn't this working? Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is the generated URL of the button_to?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a named route.

```
map.delete_account 'delete_account', :controller => 'registrations', :action => 'delete_account'
```

In which case you can do this

```
<%= button_to 'temo', '/delete_account' %>
```